# why when we change the cost of every edge in G as c'= log17（c）,every MST in G is still an MST in G′ (and vice versa)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

remarks：c' is logc with base 17
MST means (minimum spanning tree)
it's easy to prove the conclusion is correct when we use linear function to transform the cost of every edge.
But log function is not a linear function ,I could not understand why this conclusion is correct。
Supplementary notes：

> I did not consider specific algorithms, such as the greedy algorithm. I simply consider the relationship between the sum of the weights of the two trees after transformation.
> Numerically if (a + b) > (c + d) , (log a + log b) maybe not > ( logc + logd) .
> If a tree generated by G has two edge a and b ,another tree generated by G has c and d，a + b < c + d and the first tree is a MST,but in transformed graph G' ,the sum of weights of edges of second tree may be smaller.
> Because of this, I want to construct a counterexample based on "if (a + b)> (c + d), (log a + log b) maybe not> (logc + logd) ", but I failed.

Comment: c` is logc with base 17 ? Or it is log17 multiplied with c

Comment: @ZhouYuPeng, what do you mean by `log17(c)`...is `c` base or you're multiplying it with `log17` and if that's the case, then what u're using as base?

Comment: @reyad   c` is logc with base 17

Comment: @ZhouYuPeng , check my new answer, I hope it helps you understand...

Comment: @ZhouYuPeng, I just read the updated question...I missed the update actually...if you don't want to use algorithm, it becomes a problem of discrete math(specifically, topology).So, you should not tag it with algorithm. Rather tag it with discrete-math and topology. Anyway, we've started using algorithm to prove mathematics a long ago..I hope you've heard about [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem).Algorithm has been used to prove it, at first. Don't just confined yourself with some unnecessary boundary. World has changed, Mathematics has changed and changing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to characterize when a spanning tree T is a minimum spanning tree is that, for every edge e not in T, the cycle formed by e and edges of T (the *fundamental cycle* of e with respect to T) has no edge more expensive than e. Using this characterization, I hope you see how to prove that transforming the costs with any increasing function preserves minimum spanning trees.

There's a one line proof that this condition is necessary. If the fundamental cycle contained a more expensive edge, we could replace it with e and get a spanning tree that costs less than T.

It's less obvious that this condition is sufficient, since at first glance it looks like we're trying to prove global optimality from a local optimality condition. To prove this statement, let T be a spanning tree that satisfies the condition, let T' be a minimum spanning tree, and let G' be the graph whose edges are the union of the edges of T and T'. Run Kruskal's algorithm on G', breaking ties by favoring edges in T over edges not in T. Let T'' be the resulting minimum spanning tree in G'. Since T' is a spanning tree in G', the cost of T'' is not greater than T', hence T'' is a minimum spanning tree in G as well as G'.

Suppose to the contrary that T'' ≠ T. Then there exists an edge in T but not in T''. Let e be the first such edge considered by Kruskal's algorithm. At the time that e was considered, it formed a cycle C in the edges that had been selected from T''. Since T is acyclic, C \ T is nonempty. By the tie breaking criterion, we know that every edge in C \ T costs less than e. Observing that some edge e' in C \ T must have one endpoint in each of the two connected components of T \ {e}, we infer that the fundamental cycle of e' with respect to T contains e, which violates the local optimality condition. In conclusion, T = T'', hence is a minimum spanning tree in G.

If you want a deeper dive, this logic gets abstracted out in the theory of [matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid).

Answer (score 1):

Well, its pretty easy to understand...let's see if I can break it down for you:

```
c` = log_17(c) // here 17 is base
```

`log` may not be linear function...but we can say that:

```
log_b(x) > log_b(y) if x > y and b > 1 (and of course x > 0 and y > 0)
```

I hope you get the equation I've written...In words in means, consider a base "b" such that b > 1, then log_b(x) would be greater than log_b(y) if x > y.

So, if we apply this rule in your costs of `MST of G`, then we see that the edges those were selected for `G`, would still produce the least possible edges to construct MST G' if `c' = log_17(c) // here 17 is base`.

**UPDATE: As I can see you've problem understanding the proof, I'm elaborating a bit:**

I guess, you know `MST construction` is `greedy`. We're going to use `kruskal's algo` to proof why it is correct.(In case, you don't know, how kruskal's algo works, you can read it somewhere, or just google it, you'll find millions of resources). Now, Let me write some steps of kruskal's edge selection for `MST of G`:

```
// the following edges are sorted by cost..i.e. c_0 <= c_1 <= c_2 ....

c_0: A, F // here, edge c_0 connects A, F, we've to take the edge in MST
c_1: A, B // it is also taken to construct MST
c_2: B, R // it is also taken to construct MST
c_3: A, R // we won't take it to construct to MST, cause (A, R) already connected through A -> B -> R
c_4: F, X // it is also taken to construct MST
...
...
so on...
```

Now, when constructing `MST of G'`, we've to select edges which are in the form `c' = log_17(c) // where 17 is base`

Now, if we convert the edges using `log of base 17`, then `c_0` becomes `c_0'`, `c_1` becomes `c_1'` and so on...

But we, know that:

```
log_b(x) > log_b(y) if x > y and b > 1 (and of course x > 0 and y > 0)
```

So, we may say that,

```
log_17(c_0) <= log_17(c_1), cause c_0 <= c_1
in general, 
log_17(c_i) <= log_17(c_j), where i <= j
```

And now, we may say:

```
c_0` <= c_1` <= c_2` <= c_3` <= ....
```

So, the edge selection process to construct `MST of G'` would be:

```
// the following edges are sorted by cost..i.e. c_0` <= c_1` <= c_2` ....

c_0`: A, F // here, edge c_0` connects A, F, we've to take the edge in MST
c_1`: A, B // it is also taken to construct MST
c_2`: B, R // it is also taken to construct MST
c_3`: A, R // we won't take it to construct to MST, cause (A, R) already connected through A -> B -> R
c_4`: F, X // it is also taken to construct MST
...
...
so on...
```

Which is same as `MST of G`...

That proves the theorem ultimately....

I hope you get it...if not ask me in the comment what is not clear to you...

Comment: but，numerically if (a + b) > (c + d)  , (log a + log b)  maybe not > ( logc + logd)

Comment: I want to give a counter example of this conclusion. If a tree generated by G  has two edge a and b ,another tree generated by G has c and d，a + b  < c + d  and the first tree is  a MST, but in transformed graph G'  ,the sum of weights of edges of second tree  may be smaller.

Comment: well, can you? note: mst is greedy...,i'll edit my answer after a few minutes for ur understanding...give me some time... but, i would like to hear your example first pls... can u provide the example as soon as possible...

Comment: @ZhouYuPeng, if you can't provide an example...then, pls say  so as soon as possible...cause, after that I'll edit and elaborate the answer...

Comment: I understand what you mean, you are looking at it from the perspective of the MST algorithm (prim or kurskal). I did not consider specific algorithms, such as the greedy algorithm. I simply consider the relationship between the sum of the weights of the two trees after transformation.

Comment: Because of this, I want to construct a counterexample based on "if (a + b)> (c + d), (log a + log b) maybe not> (logc + logd) ", but I failed.

Comment: @ZhouYuPeng, constructing MST is greedy....it does not matter whatever algo you use...or do not use at all...but the proof I'm going to show you use the greediness of MST constructing...I'll be using kruskal in this case...it'll be better  ans easier to explain using kruskal...

Comment: @ZhouYuPeng, I've edited the answer and properly described every angle of how to prove the theorem, you've provided...i hope it'll make it easy for you to understand the proof...

Comment: I just started using this stackoverflow platform, and I don’t know if expressing gratitude is allowed, thank you very much for your enthusiastic help